# How to animate a GIF image in Cocoa and set it to not loop.

Tags: macos, cocoa, gif, nsimageview

Just as my title mentions, I want to use NSImageView, To "animate" an image, but not loop when it reaches the end of its animation.

Comment: I search and found UIImageView can achieve that, but NSImageView cannot. The way I achieve that was just fetching each individual frame  of the gif image file (for example, there was 10 frames of the gif, so I have to store 10 png files in my project), and switch them in an NSThread. That was stupid enough.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The infinite loop of a gif image is not a bad habit of the NSImageView, it is determined by a value (in Application Extension) within the gif image data. You can ask for that value by

```
NSBitmapImageRep *gifRep = // get the gif image from wherever
NSInteger loopCount = [[gifRep valueForProperty: NSImageLoopCount] integerValue];
// a lopCount of zero means: infinite
```

But you can also set that value (before sending it to the `NSImageView`). If you want the animation to stop after one loop, do this:

```
NSImage *img = [[NSImage alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:fileName]; // or similar
NSBitmapImageRep *gifRep = [[img representations] objectAtIndex:0];
[gifRep setProperty:NSImageLoopCount withValue:@(1)]; //one loop, then stop
[myImageView setImage:img];
```

Comment: my image does not animates.  NSImage *image = [NSImage imageNamed:@"play.gif"]; NSData *imageData = [image TIFFRepresentation]; NSBitmapImageRep *bitmapRep =  [NSBitmapImageRep imageRepWithData:imageData];      
        NSInteger loopCount = [[bitmapRep valueForProperty: NSImageLoopCount] integerValue]; [bitmapRep setProperty:NSImageLoopCount withValue:@(loopCount)]; NSData  *bitmapImageData = [bitmapRep representationUsingType:NSBitmapImageFileTypeGIF properties:@{}];       NSImage *img = [[NSImage alloc] initWithData:bitmapImageData];       [self.audioDeviceImageView setImage:img];

Comment: NSImageLoopCount : i have set its value to 0 / 1 / loopCount . But nothing worked

Answer (score 1):

Finally, I achieved Gif animation in NSImageView.

Xcode 8.2
OSX 10.12

```
 self.imageView.imageScaling = NSImageScaleProportionallyDown;
 self.imageView.animates = YES;
 self.imageView.canDrawSubviewsIntoLayer = YES;
 [self.imageView setImage:[NSImage imageNamed:@"play.gif"]];
```